# Lazy load modal module in angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm working with angular **version 11** and I have a module **MyModalModule** that declares modal components and the components they use.
Since the user won't open them 90% of the time, I implemented **lazy loading** for this module using the **import function of webpack** to dynamic import the module. I decided not to use the built in lazy loading of angular since my entry points are non routable (they are opened in a modal clicking a button).

Here are the files I use (not the real code, just same architecture and functions so you get the idea) :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ModalComponentA,
        ModalComponentB,
        ComponentA,
        ComponentB,
        ComponentC,
        ComponentD,
    ],
    imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, NgbModule, PipesModule],
    exports: [],
})
export class MyModalModule{
    static getModalComponentA(): typeof ModalComponentA {
        return ModalComponentA;
    }
    static getModalComponentB(): typeof ModalComponentB {
        return ModalComponentB;
    }
}
```

**my-modal.module.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LazyLoaderService{
    modalService = inject(NgbModal);

    async loadModalA(options?: NgbModalOptions): Promise<NgbModalRef> {
        const myModule = await import('../path-to-my-module');
        return this.modalService.open(myModule.MyModalModule.getModalComponentA(), options);
    }

    async loadModalB(options?: NgbModalOptions): Promise<NgbModalRef> {
        const myModule  = await import('../path-to-my-module');
        return this.modalService.open(myModule.MyModalModule.getModalComponentB(), options);
    }
}
```

**lazy-loader.service.ts**

**Everything is working fine** with this simple solution.
Otherwise, imagine I have 20 modals, I would have to define **20 functions doing the exact same thing**...

So **instead of giving the responsability to the service to provide a function for each component that can be  an entry point, I'd like to have one generic function that loads the module and open the component passed in parameter of the function in a new modal**.

I tried something that looks like :

```
 async loadModal(componentName: string, options?: NgbModalOptions): Promise<NgbModalRef> {
        const myModule = await import('../path-to-my-module');
        return this.modalService.open(myModule.MyModalModule[componentName], options);
    }
```

Otherwise, **myModule.MyModalModule[componentName] is undefined**.
So I guess you cannot get a component like that in angular, and when I checked the myModule.MyModalModule object, I didn't find anything useful.

(PS : sorry for my english, did my best..)

Comment: What is the issue you are facing when you use loadModal generic function?

Comment: I edited the question with the issue I have with this generic function.

Comment: I created [this directive](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/lazy-loading/src/lazy-load/lazy-load.directive.ts) that can be used [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/lazy-loading/lazy-loading.component.html#L3). But you will need the `import` statement in typescript, or else the code won't be deployed

Comment: Even if it doesn't really answer my question, that is actually an interesting way to lazy load components through a directive so thank you for sharing !

Comment: You could use https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler#compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync but unfortunately this is deprecated since v13

Comment: The more reliable way is to import the component itself directly by webpack dynamic import with magic comments to allow dynamic component paths. https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments

Comment: But the magic comments way needs a lot of adjustments and also you will have to disable the tree shaking to make it work.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I needed to see ! I'm going to play with those magic comments to find what suits best for me. Why do I need to disable the tree shaking though ?
And since it's a comment how can I accept your answer ? (don't have enough reputation to like comments I guess)